# Adding styles for all child HTML tags

Tags: css, reactjs

I am developing a component where based on user interactions multiple tables are created dynamically inside a div. I have some standard styles to applied on all of those tables once they are added in the DOM.

I know that i can write inline styles and can achieve this but the tables are created or destroyed at the framework level where I can't pass the custom styles. Is there some way to apply css on all child html tags like `table` within my div

Thanks

Comment: `<your div id> * { css stuff here }`

Comment: @Deckerz Almost right, you're missing an extra '>'. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0m994qcw/)

Comment: i am writing styles using the json notations like: area: { maxWidth: '500px'} , how do i use tags in these?

Comment: you put the `maxWidth: '500px'` inside the css provided

Comment: but ```area > table : { maxWidth: '500px'}``` is not a valid json

Comment: Use css modules instead of inline style?